# How do I make the text stay after reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, division

How do I make the text stay after reloading the page?
Please help.

http://pastebin.com/EnTcrULq

```js
function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="answer_list">Hello</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Button" onclick="showDiv()" />
```

Comment: I'm reloading the page and the text disappears.

Comment: in your html code you made it display: none. check it

Comment: I'm working on a web app. I'm trying to make a homescreen clone with an appstore. And after reloading the page, the icons disappears.

Comment: i think below code  (by Rino Raj ) will help you.. is it perfect solution for you...???

Comment: i tried. it didn't work :/

Comment: i think there is another problem... are you  mention display:none anywhere except #welcomeDiv

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('showWelcome') != null))
        showDiv();
    }
};

function showDiv() {
  document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
  sessionStorage.setItem('showWelcome','true'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
$(window).load(function () {
    if($('#welcomeDiv').css('display') == 'none')
   {
     showDiv();
   }
};
function showDiv()
{
$('#welcomeDiv').css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: Like this? <script>
window.onload=function(){
   if($('welcomeDiv').css('display') == 'none')
   {
     showDiv();
   }
};
function showDiv()
{
  $("welcomeDiv").css("display","block");
}

</script>
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > Hello</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Button" onclick="showDiv()" />

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button :/

Comment: Yes. And I want it to stay after reloading :/

Comment: <script>
$(window).load(function () {
    if($('#welcomeDiv').css('display') == 'none')
   {
     showDiv();
   }
};
function showDiv()
{
$('#welcomeDiv').css('display','block');
}
</script>
<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="answer_list" > Hello</div>
<input type="button" name="answer" value="Button" onclick="showDiv()" />

Comment: i am sure there is another problem,... beacause on button click you want to call showDiv() function. if there is mistake in my code , but i know my below 3 lines are correct.. you have to check your project.. like parent div of this div , or any applied styles in <style />

Comment: Could you send me the full code? With the HTML part?

Comment: daniel321m83@gmail.com

Comment: Nothing happens when I click the button :(

Comment: which software you are using...??

Comment: I'm hosting it on my server

Comment: Copied and pasted it

Comment: you have take help with another php softwares to develop the web page

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: showDiv is not defined

Comment: when.,..?? why..?? do you make some changes with js package or something else

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2012 for developing...there fore i am getting output. now if you have this sw then use it otherwise use another sw for php. and dont forget to upvote my answer...